XOpenDisplay fortran fails but C works fine
I found an Xlib interface to Fortran here. When I run a simple C code (creating X windows) all is well. But the simplest Fortran code fails.
     program simple
      use xlib

      type(c_ptr) display

      display = x_open_display_test('')       <----------------infinite loop
!      display = x_open_display('')       <---------------- returns NULL
      if(.not. c_associated(display)) then
         write(6, 901)
         stop
      end if
   901     format('Display is NULL?')
      end program simple

I modified the interface in Xlib.f90 to try to debug things, and things went to hell at the speed of light:
:
    public :: x_open_display
:
   interface
:
        ! Display *XOpenDisplay (char *display_name)
        function x_open_display(display_name) bind(c, name='XOpenDisplay')
            import :: c_char, c_ptr
            implicit none
            character(kind=c_char), intent(in) :: display_name
            type(c_ptr)                        :: x_open_display
        end function x_open_display
:
   end interface
:
    function x_open_display_test(display_name) bind(c, name='XOpenDisplay')
      character(kind=c_char), intent(in) :: display_name
      type(c_ptr)                        :: x_open_display_test
      x_open_display_test = x_open_display(display_name)
      write (6, 95)
95    format('xopen')
    end function x_open_display_test

Instead of just failing, I got 15,000 some lines of "xopen" and a seg fault.
If I call x_open_display('') the program gets a NULL response. In C the same thing works fine. Adding something to the module causes an infinite loop. Obviously I'm doing something stupid, but I can't see it.
How do I get Fortran to see the same thing C operates with?
The reason for all this is to port 50 year old "dusty deck" code to work under modern Linux. The I/O is all I want to mess with. 50 years of debugging I do not want to touch!

I don't know if it's the only reason, but in contrast to C:

Fortran strings are not terminated by a null character
the length of the string is passed in a hidden argument in function calls, and the function on the C side is not aware of this argument.

I would modify the interface like this:
interface
    ! Display *XOpenDisplay (char *display_name)
    function x_open_display(display_name) bind(c, name='XOpenDisplay')
        import :: c_char, c_ptr
        implicit none
        character(kind=c_char,len=1), intent(in) :: display_name(*)
        type(c_ptr) :: x_open_display
    end function x_open_display
end interface

And I would call the function like this:
display = x_open_display(''//c_null_char)


That works! A null character string concatenated with a null character kind of blows my mind out, but it makes sense for a single byte of 0. That should give me some clues on how to deal with other interface problems that I'm sure will come up.

The Fortran empty string '' is zero length and cannot be understood by the C side. An empty string in C is actually 1 byte long in memory, this byte between the null character. Note that ''//c_null_char is actually equivalent to c_null_char, I just left the '' in the case you would like to give a non-empty name:'some_name'//c_null_char
